# Expose the const and nonconst versions of begin() and end() to iterate member vector with smart pointer

Tags: c++, constants, smart-pointers, const-iterator

// Cat.h

```
class Cat
{public:
    void const_meow() const{ ... };
    void meow(){ ... };
};

class CatLibrary
{public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Cat>>::iterator begin()
    { 
        return m_cat_list.begin();
    }

    // compile error, the compiler complains cannot covert type
    //     from `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Cat>>::const_iterator` 
    //     to   `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const Cat>>::const_iterator`
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const Cat>>::const_iterator begin() const 
    { 
        return m_cat_list.cbegin();
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Cat>> m_cat_list;
};
```

// main.cpp

```
CatLibrary cat_library;       
cat_library.add(std::make_shared<Cat>());
cat_library.add(std::make_shared<Cat>());

for(auto& cat: cat_library )
{
   cat->const_meow(); 
   cat->meow(); 
}       
for(const auto& cat: cat_library)
{
   cat->const_meow(); 
   cat->meow();       // hope to compile error due to invoking non_const method of Cat.
}


const CatLibrary& const_cat_library = cat_library;        
for(auto& cat: const_cat_library ) 
{
   cat->const_meow(); 
   cat->meow();       // hope to compile error due to invoking non_const method of Cat.
}
const CatLibrary& const_cat_library = cat_library; 

for(const auto& cat: const_cat_library ) 
{
   cat->const_meow(); 
   cat->meow();       // hope to compile error due to invoking non_const method of Cat.
}
```

I want my CatLibrary expose the `non-const begin()` and `non-const end()` in which a client can iterate the smart pointer pointing to the mutable Cat. And the `const begin()` and `const end()` return the iterator which points the immutable one.

Then when the client iterates the const CatLibrary, I would not worry he could modify the content of Cat in library.

But the `const` added to my member function `begin()` only qualifies the pointer to be a const pointer, not the Cat it points.

Without the pointer involved, the vector with constness makes the iterator point to a element with constness also. But I want this effect also applies the element pointed by smart pointer.

I have a approach to solve my problem, but I am not sure what problems would happen in future use.

## Maintain two vectors in const and nonconst

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Cat
{public:
    void const_meow() const { std::cout << "meow" << std::endl;}
    void meow() { std::cout << "meow" << std::endl;}
};


class CatLibrary
{public:

    void add(std::shared_ptr<Cat> cat)
    {
        m_cat_list.push_back(cat);
        m_cat_const_list.push_back(cat);
    };

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Cat>>::const_iterator begin()
    { 
        return m_cat_list.begin();
    }

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const Cat>>::const_iterator begin() const
    { 
        return m_cat_const_list.begin();
    }

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Cat>>::const_iterator end()
    { 
        return m_cat_list.end();
    }

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const Cat>>::const_iterator end() const
    { 
        return m_cat_const_list.end();
    }


private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Cat>> m_cat_list;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const Cat>> m_cat_const_list;
};


int main()
{
   CatLibrary cat_library;

   cat_library.add(std::make_shared<Cat>());
   cat_library.add(std::make_shared<Cat>());
   cat_library.add(std::make_shared<Cat>());

   const CatLibrary& const_cat_library = cat_library;
   for(auto& cat: cat_library)
   {
      cat->meow();
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Or is there another solution to solve this kind of constness problem on smart pointer in vector?

Comment: I think I'd look to use something like boost's transform_iterator to do the conversion during iteration instead of maintaining two vectors.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you posted there is no need for the const versions of begin() and end(). You can use a const reference in the ranged based for loop without having const versions of those functions and you don't need the cat to be const auto& at all to call the const member function.

There may be the need of const begin() and end() if your cat_library object itself would be const, but then you couldn't add items like that.

Comment: But if I have a read only function like `void dump_cat(const CatLibrary& cat_library){ for(auto& cat : cat_library){...}; }`, then the cat_library I passed in would be a const variable.

Comment: Yes thats right, then you would indeed need const begin() and end(). You can use this: std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Cat>>::const_iterator begin() const { return m_cat_list.begin(); } to allow the iteration, although the cat object itself is still non-const and may be modified, but I cannot think of an easy way to prevent this right now.

Comment: Yeah. Without the pointer involved, the vector with constness would make iterator point to a element with constness also. But I want  this effect also applies the element pointed by smart pointer. Maybe I would check the `transform_iterator ` as Flexo said. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd actually consider turning your abstraction around and encapsulating your collection of cats.  Iterators and mutable objects are implementation details.

So write the functions in cat instead:

```
PrintCats()
PlayWithCats()
```

If your cats library isn't aware of the operations you want to perform on them, you can look at passing in function pointers.  boost::function is good for this.
You'd have a function like

```
void CatLibrary::DoStuffToCats(boost::function<void, (const Cat&)> f))
{
    std::foreach(m_cat_list.begin(), m_cat_list.end(), f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I played a little with boost::transform_iterator and it seems possible to achieve what you want, altough I find the result not satisfying. I guess DanDan suggestion to not expose implementation details to the user might be the right way to go.

Nevertheless here is the my shot for boost::transform_iterator as a reference:

```
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>

class CatLibrary
{
public:
  typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Cat>> cat_list_t;
  typedef std::function<const Cat *(const std::shared_ptr<Cat>&)> transform_t;
  typedef boost::transform_iterator<transform_t,
                                    cat_list_t::const_iterator> const_iterator;  

[...]

  const_iterator begin() const {
    return const_iterator(std::begin(m_cat_list),
                          [](const std::shared_ptr<Cat>& c) {
                            return static_cast<const Cat *>(c.get());
                          });
  }
  const_iterator end() const { // same as above ... }
};
```

The type of `cat` inside the for loops using the `const_cat_library` is now `const Cat*` and therefore calling non-const functions is not allowed. Compiling with `g++ -c --std=c++11 transform_iterator.cxx -Wall -I$BOOSTINC` (gcc version 4.8.1) yields the following errors:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'const Cat*&' from an rvalue of type 'boost::[...]::reference {aka const Cat*}'
    for(auto& cat: const_cat_library ) {
                   ^
//twice:
error: passing 'const Cat' as 'this' argument of 'void Cat::meow()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
    cat->meow();       // hope to compile error due to invoking non_const method of Cat.
              ^
```

One of the many problems that may arise is that the shared_ptr is circumvented and a user can delete the `Cat` object inside the loop.